# How to add on click to list of products in html and get the item clicked to firestore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, firebase

I'm trying to make a simple shopping cart using Django and Firebase Admin SDK, I have queried the Firestore data in a list and displayed them in HTML, now I want to add a click listener to the list of items and get the item clicked into a Firestore collection using javascript.
Now, when I click on an item other than the first item nothing happens, that is, when I click on the first item displayed on the page everything works out fine, but the other does not.

python view.py to display the items

```
def home(request):
    collection_ref = db.collection(u'products').get()
    documents = list(doc.to_dict() for doc in collection_ref)
    return render (request,'store/home.html',{'product':documents})
```

home.html

```
{% block content %}
   {% for doc in product %}
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="card" >
 <div class="card-body">
<a href="#" class="img-prod"><img class="img-fluid" id="productUrl" src="{{doc.productImage}}"  alt="{{doc.productName}}">
 <h1 class="card-title" id="productName">{{doc.name}}</h1>
 <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" id="productPrice">{{doc.price}}</p>
 <p class="card-text" id="productDescription">{{doc.description}}</p>
<button type="button" id="addtocart">Add to cart</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

js code

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      var db = firebase.firestore();
     var addToCart=document.getElementById('addtocart');

     addToCart.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{
     var image=document.getElementById('productUrl').src;
     var  productName = document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML;
     var productPrice=  document.getElementById('productPrice').innerHTML;
    db.collection("orders").add({
   pName: productName,
   price: productPrice,
   url:image
   })
   .then(function(docRef) {
  console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
   })
   .catch(function(error) {
  console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
   });
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to keep `id`s unique throughout the whole document.  `findElementById` only returns the first element that it finds, so you add a listener to the first list item only when you run

```js
var addToCart=document.getElementById('addtocart');
addToCart.addEventListener('click', (event) =>{...
```

You should define an `add_to_cart` function in your javascript that takes parameters and then in your for loop in the html you can have something like

```html
<button onclick="add_to_cart({{doc.name}},{{doc.price}})>Add to cart</button>"
```

Comment: I tried that initially, but I had an error   **addToCart is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick **

Comment: Did you define/import the function earlier in the document than calling it?

Comment: Yeah I did, but I have embedded the javascript function in the HTML page now, and its working. Thanks